# Audio interface question - number of inputs needed?

Tags: audio, interface

I m new to sound recording and I want to be able to record the following:

- a digital piano (2 line outs)
- condenser microphone

I m looking into the Safire 2i2
Are there enough inputs on this thing?

Or rather is there a way for the digital piano to use only one input instead of 2 line ins?

Do I need absolutely need an interface with more inputs or can I get away with a 2i2

Thanks and any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In a real pinch, you record your audio singing and *Midi* (rather than audio) from the piano.  Then you make a second "multitrack" pass where you play back the Midi to the piano and record its sound with your 2-channel interface.  And there you are: 3 or 4 tracks (depending on whether you record your singing mono or stereo) all of which have been recorded live.  In a manner.

But this will get old eventually.  An interface with a few additional line inputs will save you time and hassle over your recording career.

Answer (score 0):

Most digital pianos/keyboards have the option of either mono or stereo out. What you'll loose by only having a mono signal depends on the model, but it might be worth a try. If you have two in, you then have one channel for each.